# Verify encryption of ebs volumes in aws

Tags: amazon-web-services, encryption

I have an encrypted ebs volume and encrypted ebs volume
I  copy stuff from my unencrypted  volume to encrypted volume(using cp).

How do I verify that the files/directories in my encrypted volume are encrypted?

I know that the volume is encrypted. I want to know how to verify the actual files in this encrypted volumes are encrypted.

As  per documentation, encrypted ebs volumes means data at rest is encrypted. But how do I verify that

Thank you
Kumar

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't "see" the encryption. It is handled transparently by the AWS. Your EC2 instance receives already decrypted data.

From docs:

> You access encrypted volumes the same way you access other volumes; **encryption and decryption are handled transparently** and they require no additional action from you, your EC2 instance, or your application.

The encryption process happens at the hypervisor level:

> AWS KMS decrypts the encrypted data key and sends the decrypted data key to Amazon EC2. Amazon EC2 uses the plaintext data key in **hypervisor memory to encrypt disk I/O to the volume**.

One way to **verify** how it works is to create a customer managed CMK in KMS. Use that to encrypt a volume in some **dummy instance**. Then disable or delete the key. You will observer that you will not be able to start that instance again. The reason is that without access to your CMK, AWS will not be able to decrypt your volume.

Comment: Thank you  Marcin. Couple of followup questions on this one. (a) So really encryption of ebs volumes do not protect me if somebody in the same team tries to view the data. They can still mount it on their ec2 instance (consider 2 teams in the same org) and try to view the data.

Comment: @KumarMadduri Yes. This is part of [shared reponsibility](https://aws.amazon.com/compliance/shared-responsibility-model/) model at AWS. For some things AWS is responsible, of others, like securing access to your instances, it is you.

Answer (score 0):

Its not possible to do any kind of validation on individual files. The only way to validate an EBS volume is encrypted is by looking for the property on each volume. This is exposed via console and CLI.

To give a further insight into the encryption process of an EBS volume, a symmetrical customer managed key from KMS will be used to generate a data key for the EBS volume, this key will only ever be stored locally on the host machine in memory.

During operations the encryption/decryption is handled for you.

Additional Links

- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/services-ebs.html
- https://docs.aws.amazon.com/kms/latest/developerguide/concepts.html#enveloping